# How to force old wlan naming 16.04

Tags: wireless

How do I force the old wlan naming convention of wlan0, wlan1 insted of wlpn2df45ch567k? The last 12 digits are the mac address of the wireless card. It is far more cumbersome to have to type the added mac address every time you want to bring the interface up or down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration#Change_device_name) you can change the device name by defining the name manually with an udev-rule.

```
nano /etc/udev/rules.d/10-network.rules
```

Add the following line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff", NAME="net1"
```

Replace `aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff` with your mac adress and `net1` by the new device name, save and exit then reboot your system.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way

To get an wlanX back, edit the grub file.

```
 $ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Look for `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`  and add the following `net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0`.

From:

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

To:

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
```

Generate a new grub file using the following command.

```
 $ sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

 Generating grub configuration file ...
 Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-15-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-15-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
done
```

Reboot.

Answer (score 0):

[Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) is a feature of systemd. If you want to disable it you can use:

```
sudo dpkg-divert --divert /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules.inactive  --rename /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
```

imho, though it is better to rename the interface to something that you remember: create a file `/etc/systemd/network/10-wireless.link`

```
[Match]
MACAddress=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

[Link]
Name=wireless0
```

Comment: I sometimes use macchanger to change my mac for the wifi card. Will renaming the interface allow macchanger to change the mac? I have just noticed that macchanger doesn't stick after ifconfig wlpn2df45ch567k up.